# Fastest Way To Create an Array of a NumberSequence

Tags: c#

I would like to create an array with  of length X, and i would like the following 'inteligence'

if , for exemple, X = 6,
myArray[x] = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

For the moment, i do

```
int[] availableIndex = new int[DestructiblesCubes.Count];
for (var i = 0; i < availableIndex.Length; i++)
{
    availableIndex[i] = i;
}
```

But, i'm curious, is there a better (the faster way to execute it) and/or the faster(the shortest char length) way?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please specify *fast* (*better*)... fast execution time or a short way to achieve the goal?

Comment: since i'm just curious, Booth :D

Comment: I might be wrong but you cannot have the optimum for both You can have shortest code or you can have fastest code but not both.

Comment: Yes, but i mean, I wan't to know the faster to execute solution, and thzfaster to write.

Comment: As far as I know Artiom showed you the fastest to write version and you already use the fastest to execute version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the *fastest* method uses the `unsafe` context together with a proper `fixed` pointer to the array, as demonstrated below:

```
/*const*/ int availableIndex_Length = 6;
int[] availableIndex = new int[availableIndex_Length];
unsafe {
    fixed(int* p = &availableIndex[0]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < availableIndex_Length; ++i) {
            *(p+i) = i;
        }
    } 
}
```

This can be refactored to a method, optionally `inline`d:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
static unsafe void FillRange(ref int[] array) {
      int length = array.Length;
      fixed(int* p = &array[0]) {
          for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
              *(p + i) = i;
          }
      }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    // Example usage:
    int[] availableIndices = new int[6];
    FillRange(ref availableIndices);

    // Test if it worked:
    foreach(var availableIndex in availableIndices) {
        Console.WriteLine(availableIndex);
    }
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is short way to implement this. Not the performance best solution.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray()
```

MSDN description for [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Note, that this is less code but much slower than using a for-loop when it comes to execution time.

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms totally agree, this is answer to question of `faster(the shortest char length) way`

Comment: Thx! , didn't knew this solution, is just for the "knowledge" i won't use it :)

Comment: @Crocsx didn't know your too.

Answer (score 1):

The only optimisation I can see to apply to your code as it stands is to count down to zero, but any increase in performance will be *tiny*

```
int[] availableIndex = new int[DestructiblesCubes.Count];
for (var i = availableIndex.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    availableIndex[i] = i;
}
```

Otherwise, especially if you're talking large arrays, one thing to try would be to create an array greater than your max envisioned value of DestructiblesCubes.Count and
Intialize that array as above, then use `Array.Copy` when you want the smaller array.
I would be confident that no code we hand roll will be faster than a single call to `Array.Copy`.

```
int[] availableIndex = new int[DestructiblesCubes.Count];
Array.Copy(LargeArray, availableIndex, availableIndex.Length);
```

Otherwise I can't think of anything that might be faster than the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
unsafe
{
    int[] availableIndex = new int[DestructiblesCubes.Count];
    int length = availableIndex.Length;
    int n = 0;
    fixed(int *p = availableIndex) {
        while(n < length) *p++ = n++;
    }
}
```

*may be* faster, depending on the optimization stage of your compiler.